# How can I add borders?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have just installed Android Studio 2.2 from 1.5, and so there are a lot of changes I am getting used to. In the layout editor, I want to have a border around the phones:

[image]

Notice how only the contents of the device are showing, and so it is difficult to differentiate which part is the preview editor, how can I make it look more like an actual phone with borders:

[image]

Thanks in advance, please let me know.

Ruchir

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking how to show a phone skin in the layout editor as you design your UI. Is that correct?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, so I could see the borders of the phone screen as part of the layout preview.

Answer (score 1):

It seems AS 2.2 doesn't have an option to show android phone skin in the editor area. Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html) post

But you can see everything on a phone screen in the editor for e.g. the status bar and bottom black navigation area. Note that bottom black navigation area appears only for phone models that support it. You won't get it in nexus one but will get it in nexus 4. You can select correct model from the top bar in the editor area.

Also the toolbar will appear correctly if it is added properly in the xml. This is how I see the basic screen in my editor

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.sample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.sample.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that borders are not possible in the new AS? It doesn't say that on the link provided

Comment: Link has an editor area screen shot and there you won't find any option to enable device skin, I hope you see the same on your editor. Why at all you want to see device skin? Isn't it enough to see full screen with systems bars and decorations?

Answer (score 0):

At the top right of the preview window, there is a blue gear. Click on this an be sure that "Include device frames" is checked. In AS 2.1.2, it seems to be checked by default, but for some reason the device frame does not show. I was able to get it to appear by clicking on the button on the top left of the toolbar in the preview window (the one with the page icon and an Android head) and selecting any of the "Preview ..." options, then clicking the button again and selecting "None". It appears that this feature doesn't quite work the way I would expect it to.

Comment: Hm...is it different on Macs? I don't see a blue gear in the top right.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot pointing at where it is for you?

Comment: I am unable to get a screenshot for you right at this moment. When I say "top right" it is the top right of the preview area. There are other windows further to the right with properties and such. (Sorry, I am doing this from memory ATM as I'm not on my computer with AS installed.)

Comment: It's totally fine, I really appreciate you helping me out right now. So I can see the windows, and in the preview area (left of the properties), there is no blue gear. I have attached a screenshot, please let me know! http://imgur.com/a/K7bYv

Comment: In Android Studio 2.1.2 on Windows, there is a blue gear just to the left of the "Properties" window. It appears there is a difference, either with AS 2.2 or with the Mac version.

Comment: What's the red square with the number 1 in it? What happens when you click it?

Comment: And what about the button with the phone icon?

Comment: The red square just shows that I should not hardcode my strings, but instead use the @strings resource, which is not necessary.

Comment: The red square is supposed to show warnings and errors in the layout I believe.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Here's what my toolbar looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SIzz5.png. The options in your phone button are under the android head button on mine (plus other options).

Comment: Hm...Yeah thats a totally different UI than what I see. Maybe it is because you have AS 2.1.2 and I have AS 2.2 Preview 7 (honestly I don't know what the preview 7 means). According to random's answer, it's impossible to have borders in 2.2, but that seems odd...why would Google just remove that feature in one small update from 2.1.2 to 2.2?